# reconstruction of modulated signal from envelope

Tags: matlab

I have carrier signal multiplied with `hamming window` (can be called as modulated signal). Every `20 samples` of this signal is averaged and formed envelope of it (Which looks like hamming window).
Now the task is to `get back the modulated signal`. I tried my best, but not able to `reconstruct it from the envelope`. Can anyone pls help me solving the issue.

Thanks in advance !
--Ashwini

Comment: Which type of modulation? I suppose modulation of amplitude ... so back to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation) :)

Comment: I not able to post image as i need min 10 reputations.. thats ok. Question is I have a modulated signal, which is not demodulated in standard way but averaged it and got the envelope. Now the requirement is to get back the modulated signal from the averaged data. Hope question is clear .. This is typical requirement, and in the link mentioned by you, it is not explained to retrieve the modulated signal from demodulated ..

Comment: Averaging is just a low-pass filter; this is not sufficient for demodulation...

Comment: But assuming we're talking about AM, the original signal is just the envelope multiplied by the carrier.

Comment: Thanks for reply.This is not AM application. But NMR (non Magnetic resonance), where hamming window is multiplied with carrier & transmitted. The reflected signal is digitised using ADC,the ADC otput is multiplied with local sin & cos signals then averaged over 20 consecutive samples & sent for further processing. This is all about entire process i m working on.this is our client requirement that data has to be averaged & sent to other module and in other module it needs to be reconstructed. Which i m not able to do.They are interested in reconstructing the ADC output from the averaged data

Comment: If you are *multiplying* a carrier by a signal, then you have AM.

Comment: NMR = *nuclear* magnetic resonance. Could help with your client.